# how to get array objects value in jquery

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

i am getting this response after ajax post

```
Array
(
    [curve] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date1] => 2018

                    [total1] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date1] => 2018

                    [total1] => 200
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date1] => 2018

                    [total1] => 0
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date1] => 2018

                    [total1] => 0
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [date1] => 2018

                    [total1] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

and my post request is as below:

```
$.post("<?=base_url();?>app/total_meter_feeder_r_curve", { divid: divid,id:id}, function(result)
            {
                alert(result);
                        $('.basefp').hide();

                        // chart.series[0].setData([first,second]);
            });
```

i want to retrieve value on ajax success of "total1" only . how could i achieve this. on alerting result i am getting the above array.

Comment: You need to use `$.each` method of jquery like `$.each(result, function(index, value) {
  alert(value);
});`

Comment: `result.curve[0]->total1`, arrow is used for accessing stdClass Object. I haven't tested the code though.

Answer (score 4):

So basically you have got `result` in response of ajax success , 
result variable is array of objects. Hence Now you have to travel into this array, so the `total1` is a variable in one of object in array of result['curve'].

If you try below snippet your problem should get resolve:

```
jQuery.each(result['curve'], function(index, value) { 
        alert(value.total1); 
});
```